# Spin glass observables in Monte Carlo simulations

Tags: thermodynamics, simulations, ising-model, lattice-model, spin-models

I am currently simulating an Edwards-Anderson spin glass using standard Metropolis Monte Carlo techniques. The spins are placed on a 3D cubic lattice with periodic boundaries and take on Ising values (-1/+1), the couplings between them are drawn from a Gaussian random distribution.

What's now unclear to me is how I technically implement typical spin glass observables, such as the Edwards-Anderson order parameter:
$$q_{EA} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \langle\sigma_i\rangle^2 $$

According to this definition, I first do thermal averages for each of the sites independently, and afterwards average over the system. Finally, I might do another average of independent disorder replicas.

So, in practice, how would one implement such an observable? Keeping track of the thermal "history" of *every* site throughout the entire simulation seems tedious and will be expensive once the lattice becomes larger. And even worse, observables such as the spin glass susceptibility
$$\chi_{SG} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i,j}^N \langle\sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle^2 $$
require to record the history of every *pair* of sites...

- *Literature: Parisi, Giorgio. "Order parameter for spin-glasses." Physical Review Letters 50.24 (1983): 1946.*

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633) is used. It'd be great if you could use it in your next posts.